# Android: Facebook Login: The App has no Android Key hashes configured

Tags: android, facebook, android-facebook

I am trying to get Facebook Login to work in my Android App:

Here's the partial code for this:

```
   private void performFacebookLogin()
                {
                    final Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(this, Arrays.asList("email"));
                    Session openActiveSession = Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback()
                    {
                     ...
                    }
                }
```

But when this code is invoked, the Facebook Login page shows up with this error message:

The App has no Android Key hashes configured. Configure your app key hashes at: http://developers.facebook.com/apps/AppID

On the developers page, i see no way of providing any hash key either, and am not sure how to generate the hash key itself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to generate Key hashes for your android application. Follow the instructions given in Facebook integration quick start guide. And follow the instructions given in the attached screens 1,2,3,4,5. Once you added Key hashes you are done. And check the facebook integration code. It will work without any trouble.

Link for Facebook integration quick start guide [facebook quick start](https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/)

Instruction image for reference

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

Hope this helps you

Comment: Existing App ... no way to change the key hash?

Comment: You can change the existing app also. Select your app from the developer console and select "Settings" options from the left panel. You can find "Key hashes" section.

Comment: If not find select "Settings" from left panel and select "Add platform" select android.

Answer (score 0):

They have changed this SDK follow the new [Facebook sdk](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/v2.3)

Answer (score 0):

Steps to add to solve this problem:

open to https://developers.facebook.com/apps/
Select your default App
On side menu, select **App Settings -> Basic Settings**
At the bottom click on **Add Platform** ->  **Create an app for Android**
Enter the Hash Key, package name, class name,

Save and you are fine...

Answer (score -2):

It's mentioned in the Facebook documentation :

> To authenticate the exchange of information between your app and the
>   Facebook, you need to generate a release key hash and add this to the
>   Android settings within your Facebook App ID. Without this, your
>   Facebook integration may not work properly when you release your app
>   to the store.

You can follow steps here : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started#release-key-hash

Steps to register the hash key:

1. Enter to https://developers.facebook.com/apps/
2. Create an app for Android
3. Select `Setting` tab from the left side
4. Enter the package name, class name and Hash Key
5. Turn your app live from the `Status & Review tab`

Comment: Fouad > I do not see hash key form field on developers page itself

Comment: you have to create a Facebook App and then register your app hash key in this App : here's the link , https://developers.facebook.com/settings/developer/sample-app/

Comment: The app exists of course, but i see no way of adding hash key for my own app

Comment: Fouad> This is an existing app. So it appears that hash key cannot be added/updated to an existing app - as there is no option for that.

Comment: Nope , please be sure that your existing app is created for android , then if it's once you open this link : https://developers.facebook.com/settings/developer/sample-app/ , you can edit your hash key

Comment: @downvoter shame on you,  you think you have enough knowledge to judge my answer as not useful ?